# Converting json to slice of maps and slice of maps to json in Go without using structs

Tags: json, string, interface, go

I am trying to convert a json string from an http request to a slice of map/s.
And I should also convert a slice of map/s to json string to use for a http response.

I want to convert the followings into a slice of map/s, in both cases below.
The json string from the http request may be an array of several same key value json objects, like;

```
[
        { title: 'JavaScript: The Good Parts', author: 'Douglas Crockford',
          releaseDate: '2008', keywords: 'JavaScript Programming' },
        { title: 'The Little Book on CoffeeScript', author: 'Alex MacCaw',
          releaseDate: '2012', keywords: 'CoffeeScript Programming' },
        { title: 'Scala for the Impatient', author: 'Cay S. Horstmann',
          releaseDate: '2012', keywords: 'Scala Programming' },
        { title: 'American Psycho', author: 'Bret Easton Ellis',
          releaseDate: '1991', keywords: 'Novel Splatter' },
        { title: 'Eloquent JavaScript', author: 'Marijn Haverbeke',
          releaseDate: '2011', keywords: 'JavaScript Programming' }
]
```

or a single one like;

```
{ title: 'Eloquent JavaScript', author: 'Marijn Haverbeke',
  releaseDate: '2011', keywords: 'JavaScript Programming' }
```

And the second task is to convert a slice of  map/s to a json string.

However, I could not mange to succeed in these two procedures.

json package makes it possible to do these two tasks for structs, I am aware of it.

I should not use structs coded beforehand, for a design concern.

Is there a known way to do  these in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can use use `map[string]interface{}` and that would work with `{ "title": ....., "keywords": ["CoffeeScript", "Programming"] }` just fine

You'd have to use something like :

```
for i := 0; i < len(b); i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%s by %s was release at %s\n", b[i]["title"], b[i]["author"])
    switch v := b[i]["keywords"].(type) {
    case []interface{}:
        for i := 0; i < len(v); i++ {
            switch v := v[i].(type) {
            case string:
                fmt.Println("\tstring in a slice", v)
            case float64: //numbers in json are float64 by default
                fmt.Println("\tnumber in a slice", v)
            default:
                fmt.Printf("\tunknown type (%T)", v, v)
            }
        }
    case string:
        fmt.Println("\tstring", v)
    }
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/n-D26jAjQf)

Comment: I understand from you answer that the solution of the nested nature of the problem I tell is related to `interface{}`. I do not know how to use it. I will study it. Maybe I should remind you I am not trying to print things.

Comment: ^ that's how you use it, i'll added a more detailed example

Comment: @FarukSelcuk note that inside the switches, v is the proper type, so in `case string` v is a string, etc.

Comment: As some of you may guess why of I avoid structs, they makes code unmaintainable in the case I'll describe below. I am trying to query and exec on an sql database from Go for a web app. When I change a model at client side or a table column at database side I definitely must change the corresponding Go struct and chained to that the database querying/execing functions that use data from outside Go as struct flieds. Another point: Using Structs one cannot make Sql statements column names dynamically. I am trying to abstract one step further from that common approach.

Comment: But in slice of map usage ice of mine first yielded another problem I have stated above with my talk with @pyk, which he has pointed first, "I see a map's keys type values type predetermined and be single typed but a json's not". But now I see the solution path. Thanks.

Comment: Is that, utilising of interface{}, is kind of dynamizing the type strictness of the Golang as I understand so I haven't study it yet?

Comment: @FarukSelcuk in a way yes, it also doesn't do compile time checks and is slower than using a real type.

Comment: @OneOfOne thanks for pointing out. I learn so much from your answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: And how to do this for structs I have code but returns not the things I expect it to do?http://play.golang.org/p/eK51vvuFv9

Comment: @fsc You have to export the fields (capitalize the first letter of each field in the struct).

Comment: when I capitalise field names of struct definition it works.http://play.golang.org/p/yL7oZxKbN8

Comment: Is it difficult/possible to implement a utility only one time to do json map conversion for every nested kind of json, one may have values as values, arrays, and json objects. And would it be efficient compared to writing down every struct for table and every query function for each one separately?

Answer (score 1):

you should use `json.NewDecoder` to convert JSON to slice of maps and `json.NewEncoder` to convert slice of maps into JSON.

i wrote it here http://play.golang.org/p/jbXYGC5pp2

see explanation in the comment.

i hope this help

Comment: Is that possible with the nested json objects for example when a value is an array like `keywords` key's value in the following string `[
        { title: 'JavaScript: The Good Parts', author: 'Douglas Crockford',
          releaseDate: '2008', keywords: ["JavaScript", "Programming"] }, ...`

Comment: @FarukSelcuk it's possible when using struct. In case you want use maps instead, i think it's not possible because maps is only key value pair

Comment: Theoretically it should be possible to implement a full parser that can dig into infinitely deeply nested jsons, i.e. (every) json, and vice versa, by writing of functions on strings. But it seems not possible to me for near. Surprised it does not exist and what exists is having one thing done while rest of the possibilities left, or because they are impossible.

Comment: I see a map's keys type values type predetermined and be single typed but a json's not.

Comment: @FarukSelcuk actually json spec says an object's key must be a string and quoted with `"`.